# Powershell: How Can I get the random property of get-service cmdlet?

Tags: properties

I have:

```
$services = get-service | get-random -count 5 | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status, *HERE I WANT 2 RANDOM PROPERTIES*
```

I created a list of random properties:

```
$randomPropertyName = get-service | get-member | Where-Object memberType -eq property | get-random -count 2 | Select-Object name
```

and i cannot convert it from object.array to string, I tried:

```
[string]$random1 = $randomPropertyName[0] | ft -hidetableheaders
```